# Display part of a string in layout

Tags: android, string, android-layout, simplecursoradapter

I am reading data from an SQLite database using a cursor and using an adapter to display it in a listView. This works fine but I now want to reduce the amount of data that I show in the listView. At the moment it displays the following:

```
John Smith, 25, Moday, Consultation, Dr. Harley
Jane Doe, 41, Wednesday, Surgery, Dr. Pope
```

What I want it to display is:

```
John Smith, 25, Mo, Con, Harley
Jane Doe, 41, We, Sur, Pope
```

Basically I want to parse 3 of the strings. The problem is the cursor adapter takes the columns of the database as a string array in its constructor so I don't know where to perform the parsing operation on it. I've tried a number of different options and am getting unrecognised column id errors and other runtime errors. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

The method where the adapter is created:

```
private void fillList() {
        Cursor c = db.getApts();
        startManagingCursor(c);

        String[] from = new String[] {ModuleDB.KEY_AptCode,
                          ModuleDB.KEY_AptName,
                          ModuleDB.KEY_AptAge,
                          ModuleDB.KEY_AptDay,
                          ModuleDB.KEY_AptType,
                                  ModuleDB.KEY_AptDoc};
        int[] to = new int[] {R.id.Aptcode_entry,
                      R.id.AptName_entry,
                      R.id.AptAge_entry,
                      R.id.Aptday_entry,
                              R.id.Apttype_entry,
                              R.id.Aptdoc_entry};

        SimpleCursorAdapter aptAdapter = 
                new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.apt_entry, c, from, to);
        setListAdapter(aptAdapter);

    }
```

Comment: Please show your adapter.  Under the principal of separation of concerns, this is where you should do the parsing.

Comment: Are each of these individual textviews or one text view? In your adapter you should be parsing. Post your adapter code. The parsing should happen in the getView method and it should be a simple matter of using substring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) Let your activity implement - ViewBinder

2.) Match your column and use substring

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity
    implements SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder {

   adapter.setViewBinder(this); //Put this line after your list creation and setlistAdapter


    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int column) {
     //Showing for day, similarly for others
        int dayColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(your day column name in quotes);
        if (column == dayColumn ) {
            String dayString = cursor.getString(dayColumn );
            ((TextView)view).setText(bodyString.subString(0, 3));

            return true; // Return true to show you've handled this column
        }
        return false;
    }
```

}

Also - @Simon is Right - Using a Custom Adapter that extends a Cursor Adapter is always better because you get a lot more freedom to modify it later if your requirements evolve further. Off the top of my head here is an example of how you can use custom adapter and build a nice list- http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what adapter you use, but assuming all the data is shown as single row then I'd extend that one and override `toString()` method of it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think you can override toString() on a simple adapter but perhaps this will help?

```
SimpleCursorAdapter aptAdapter= new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.apt_entry, c, from, to);

 CursorToStringConverter stringConverter = new CursorToStringConverter() {    
    @Override
    public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
       return "Hello listview"; // whatever string you want to build using cursor.getString() etc
    }
 }; 

 aptAdapter.setCursorToStringConverter(stringConverter);
```

[EDIT] Just checked the docs and SimpleCursorAdapter does not have a toString() method, nor do any of it's super classes.

Comment: thanks very much for that. Am I going about this the right way then? Should I be looking at a different type of cursor to start with?

Comment: It's not a question of the cursor, since it's only job is to return data.  Whenever I've done this, I've always wanted to show to data in very specific ways - formatted columns,different colours, rows highlighted etc so I've always just created my own adapters.   But SimpleCursorAdapter is, as the name implies, as simple as it gets.  Just seen Slaribarfast's solution and I actually think it's better than mine since to use a string converter, you must also use a filter (which can be configured to return everthing) but his solution is cleaner.

Comment: I will mark Slartibartfast's solution as correct but I think I will look into a custom adapter instead. Thanks for your input